# cassandra,solr,lucandra,solandra

Tags: cassandra, solandra

I am developing a site using following technologies,

Ruby on Rails,(ruby 1.8.7,rails 2.3.5)
Cassandra 0.6.8,

I want to index the Cassandra Database using Lucandra,
How do I do this?
Is there any RESTful APIs or any web services available for this, so
that I can push the data to index database?
Please share if any ROR example using Lucandra, that really help us to
move forward.
Or Guide me some steps to achieve this.

I am googling for 3 days and I am not getting any examples using
Lucandra in ROR.

Your help will be appreciated in advance

Comment: The `*andra` technologies are all rather new. When you are dealing with new technology, you must experiment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Solandra project which is replacing Lucandra no longer uses
thrift, only Solr. http://github.com/tjake/Lucandra

This means you can use any of the Solr supported gems like
acts_as_solr

Comment: thanks,but act_as_solr uses ActiveRecord,In my application ActiveRecord support is not available because of cassandra database ,Please let me know How I can use acts_as_solr in my application

Answer (score 1):

I'm recommending elasticsearch. It has rest api, ruby & rails clients.

https://github.com/angelf/escargot

https://github.com/grantr/rubberband

Elasticsearch is the most advanced free search solution in the world today. It's based on lucene, has High Availability, fault tolerant, partitioned, high performance, scalable, state of art technologhy , open source, more simple than solr... It's success belongs to it's author Shay Banon. He has years of experience as an architect in this field. Solr (and solandra) is nowhere near of it. Simply investigate both, you'll see yourself.

my best

Serdar

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,one thing here I am not able to use ActiveRecord.Is it support without activerecord,if so let me know